# Modify Document upload form sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013

I am interested in document upload form in SharePoint 2013. 
I wonder if there is some way to create conditions on some fields to fill in  when uploading the document.

To Keep is simple, for instance, I upload the document. 
I add title, document type, and the next column in upload form  is "Type" drop down list with 2 Options - fruits and vegetables (just to Keep it simple)

next column is the list of objects....  If earlier I choose fruits, I want to see in this column drop down only  bananas & apples but no cucumbers or salad. if I choose vegetables - I want to see other Options to select from. This is the idea.

is it possible?

Comment: I think the InfoPath with some rule(get list of object based on Type column) will work on your case, but one reminder the InfoPath doesn't support anymore from Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

It sure is. Create a view and select which items to show in the view. On the document library headers, click the more menu ( . . . ) and select Create View.

[image]

When you have the new view, you can upload documents their (but you will see all fruit and salad options on the upload document modal). If you only want to see these options you need to make a custom solution where you filter options in JavaScript using JSOM or CSOM.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a no-code solution, InfoPath is the only way, besides external tools. I wouldn't go there as it is deprecated and you might need to rebuild your solution.

There is a javscript library called SPServices. This is really helpful in certain scenario's https://spservices.codeplex.com/.

And this is the function you are looking for: https://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=$().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns&referringTitle=Documentation